# Which database should I use for large video streaming website and huge users base website?

Tags: php, video, database-design, video-streaming

I am analyzing one big project where following are list of main PUV (Perceived user value) of customer.

- 60k to 70K users will browse the site at a time and should able to register. Needs fast processing.
- Uploading of video (Though I am thinking to go with third party video management service to store & fetch the videos)
- Browsing of videos by at least 25K users at a time, e.g. one single video may be playing at a time by thousands of users.
- Video live streaming
- Payment transactions for membership (say thousands of users will upgrade membership at a time)

We have decided to go with PHP framework but at the moment not sure about,

1. Which database should we use?
2. Which third party video management service should we use?
3. Which server should we go?

Please advise.

Comment: Try Windows azure. You will get all your answers [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/)

Answer (score 0):

Check adobe media server. I think its not the db that you be worried right now, but its the right CDN.
Use a good content delivery network like rackspace or amazon. Get a good media server and you are ready to go. CDN's provide good balancer and scalable support.